# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'author'

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I'm building a discord bot and I have a problem with attribute error and I hope someone will correct me. It should run but it is showing me this error:

> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'author'

````
import asyncio
import aiohttp
import json
from discord import Game
from discord.ext.commands import Bot


BOT_PREFIX = ('?', '!')
TOKEN = ""

client = Bot(command_prefix=BOT_PREFIX)

@client.command(name='8ball',
                description="Answers a yes/no question.",
                brief="Answers from the beyond.",
                aliases=['eight_ball', 'eightball', '8-ball'],
                pass_context=True)
async def eight_ball(context):
    possible_responses = [
        'That is a resounding no',
        'It is not looking likely',
        'Too hard to tell',
        'It is quite possible',
        'Definitely',
    ]
    await client.process_commands(random.choice(possible_responses) + ", " + context.message.author.mention)


client.run(TOKEN)```
````

Comment: `context.message` is a string not what you think it is.

Comment: how can i fix this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, reset your token as soon as possible. Your bot is now compromised and everyone on the internet has access to it.

Now regarding your issue: You simply need to change `context.message.author` to `context.author`.

Answer (score 0):

[`Bot.process_commands`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Bot.process_commands) requires a `Message` object, but you're passing it a string instead.

The purpose of `process_commands` is to give you control of when commands are processed in your `on_message` event.  If you don't supply an `on_message` event, the default one will call `process_commands` for you.

It looks like you're trying to send a message back to the place the command was called from.  You can do this by using `Context.send` to send a message directly to the invocation context (this is really just a shorthand for `ctx.channel.send`)

```
@client.command(name='8ball',
                description="Answers a yes/no question.",
                brief="Answers from the beyond.",
                aliases=['eight_ball', 'eightball', '8-ball'],
                pass_context=True)
async def eight_ball(context):
    possible_responses = [
        'That is a resounding no',
        'It is not looking likely',
        'Too hard to tell',
        'It is quite possible',
        'Definitely',
    ]
    await context.send(random.choice(possible_responses) + ", " + context.message.author.mention)
```